# NSAppTransportSecurity exception for google blob images

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, https, app-transport-security

We building an iOS app and are serving images using [google's blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/images/#Go_Serving_and_re-sizing_images_from_the_Blobstore) in an iOS app. We get image urls that start with domains like:

```
 http://lh4.ggpht.com
```

iOS [blocks http requests](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) by default.

Because we aren't in control of this URL, I need to configure an HTTP exception for my iOS app. I want to be responsible and include an exception that is as specific as I can.

- Can I trust that `*.gghpt.com` is a stable domain for this service?

Comment: ServingURLOptions lets you set Secure: true to get an https url, but if you change the http in your existing urls to https they should load.

Comment: We saw that we could always use https (but this makes requests slower and less cacheable I think).

Comment: [You can always serve the images from a secure route on your app, using the Blobstore service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/#Go_Serving_a_blob).

Comment: We don't feel these images need to be secured. Using HTTPS introduces caching downsides and handshake overhead.